# html charset working different on 2 servers

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, xhtml

I've a website that was developed on my linux server. I'm from Brazil so we do have latin characters like é á ã, etc...I'm using charset=ISO-8859-1 on my website and everything works:

http://www.kbytes.com.br/siteitau/

The problem is that this site was moved to another server and now it's all messed up:

http://sites.itaucultural.org.br/cinemadebordas/

Some of the texts are coming from the database, but all places that I have a latin character is not working. I have no idea how to fix it....any ideas?

Comment: Did you set your default connection, database char-set, on new server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like apache is set to deliver UTF8.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Either change it in the apache conf or try setting a [charset directive in htaccess](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html)

Comment: I think you can just `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');` at the top of the page and that will sort it out. But +1, this is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Either in the apache settings (would be global for whole server) or, as I said, via htaccess (would be valid for the directory htaccess is in only) or, as DaveRandom said, by putting the `header(...)` on top of your php file(s), which would be valid for those file(s) only.